# SOAP Error in Magento

Tags: magento, soap-client

I am continuously getting this error in my server error log for my magento enterprise website. E_ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.nubianheritage.com/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Invalid XML encoding name I have been searching for this issue but still not getting any proper solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
Step 1:
        error : PHP extension "soap" must be loaded. in magento
Step 2: Open xampp server
step 3: Apache/ config click ok button
step 4:
        ctrl + f
        find soap
        and remove ;
after
   ;extension=php_soap.dll 
before
   extension=php_soap.dll

step 5: save this file
step 6: restart xampp server visitors to your blog will always go to https://w3free.blogspot.com.
```